# Can every iterative algorithm be viewed as gradient descent over some objective?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, descent

In [Algorithms for Non-negative Matrix Factorization](http://hebb.mit.edu/people/seung/papers/nmfconverge.pdf), Lee and Seung give multiplicative algorithms derived from gradient descent on the Frobenius norm to find a non-negative matrix factorization.

Elsewhere, I've seen iterative algorithms where the convergence is proved not via gradient descent but via some contraction mapping fixed point theorem or something like that. I'm wondering whether every iterative algorithm can be rewritten as gradient descent on some objective function.

Comment: There may be problems with iterative methods that fail (e.g., Newton's method gets caught in a cycle).

Comment: I'm coming from a programmer's perspective, so I might be missing the mathematical definition of an iterative function, but to my mind the answer depends on whether the function itself diverges or not. Or am I misunderstanding your question and should it be read like 'can every *converging* iterative algorithm be viewed as gradient descent'?

Comment: @Fasermaler Hm I'm not sure we need to specify that. For example, gradient descent will diverge on any section of a function that looks like 1/x

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If the 'step size' is not chosen appropriately in gradient descent, doesn't it fail in the same way that Newton's method might fail, i.e. by 'overshooting'?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would classify trust region methods in this context.

Comment: @user43228 Ah right, thanks for the clarification. I was thinking of a pathological case where gradient descent misbehaves.